# How to get specific object item from array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, html-table

I'm having this map function to map through some table data.

```
const Rows = dataToFilter.children.map((row: any) => {
    return row.table_row;
  });
console.log("ROWSSS", Rows);
```

...and as a result i'm getting this complex array of objects:

[image]

How can i get the two columns of arrays highlited?

Comment: `=> row.table_row.cells.slice(0,2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't have the data to test, but this could be a possibility

```
const Rows = dataToFilter.children.map((row: any) => {
  const [colOne, colTwo] = row.table_row.cells;

  return {
    colOne,
    colTwo
  }

});
```

Comment: This solution is identical to my answer, only unnecessary more elaborate. I don't give answers to such simple questions but only in the OP's main question's comment, because at this level of simplicity, there is not need for an answer.

Comment: Thank you guys. At the moment i think i did learn something, i come to problems like this which i don't have any idea how to solve, then someone like you come and solves it so easily which makes me question my knowledge lol.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
const Rows = dataToFilter.children.map((row: any) => {
    return [row.table_row.cells[0], row.table_row.cells[1]];

  });

console.log("ROWSSS", Rows);
```